# split list to list of list by matching pattern in python

Tags: python

I have a list with filenames

```
names = ['REGION_5_64_5_col1_row1_B1.tiff', 'REGION_5_64_5_col2_row2_B1.tiff',
'REGION_5_1_2_col_row_B1.tiff','REGION_5_8_3_col_row_B1.tiff']
```

And I need to split it with the help of substring before column information like `REGION_5_64_5, REGION_5_1_2, REGION_5_8_3`

So the output would be

```
[['REGION_5_64_5_col1_row1_B1.tiff', 'REGION_5_64_5_col2_row2_B1.tiff],
[REGION_5_1_2_col_row_B1],[REGION_5_8_3_col_row_B1]]
```

Not sure how it could be achieved without very verbose code in a for loop.

Comment: Do all the names start with the same pattern? Are all of them like this `'REGION_X_X_X'`?

Comment: `for` loop seems like quiet reasonable approach.

Comment: [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) might help.

Comment: @alonkh2 yes they start with the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sort your `names` list before using `groupby`

```
import itertools

key = lambda k: k.rsplit('_', 3)[0]
data = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(names, key=key), key=key)]
```

Output:

```
>>> data
[['REGION_5_1_2_col_row_B1.tiff'],
 ['REGION_5_64_5_col1_row1_B1.tiff', 'REGION_5_64_5_col2_row2_B1.tiff'],
 ['REGION_5_8_3_col_row_B1.tiff']]
```

Comment: this looks like the only correct use of `groupby` ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
[list(v) for _, v in groupby(names, key=lambda x: x.split('_')[1:4])]
```

---

```
[['REGION_5_64_5_col1_row1_B1.tiff', 'REGION_5_64_5_col2_row2_B1.tiff'], ['REGION_5_1_2_col_row_B1.tiff'], ['REGION_5_8_3_col_row_B1.tiff']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the below is what you are looking for. The idea is to collect the names by region.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
names = ['REGION_5_64_5_col1_row1_B1.tiff', 'REGION_5_64_5_col2_row2_B1.tiff',
         'REGION_5_1_2_col_row_B1.tiff', 'REGION_5_8_3_col_row_B1.tiff']

for name in names:
    parts = name.split('_')
    key = tuple(parts[0:4])
    data[key].append(name)
for k,v in data.items():
    print(f'{k} -> {v}')
```

output

```
('REGION', '5', '64', '5') -> ['REGION_5_64_5_col1_row1_B1.tiff', 'REGION_5_64_5_col2_row2_B1.tiff']
('REGION', '5', '1', '2') -> ['REGION_5_1_2_col_row_B1.tiff']
('REGION', '5', '8', '3') -> ['REGION_5_8_3_col_row_B1.tiff']
```